# Has anyone used the Papyrus toolkit in an iPhone / iPad application to view DICOM images?

Tags: iphone, ipad, dicom

Does anyone have any experience integrating the [Papyrus toolkit](http://www.sim.hcuge.ch/papyrus/01_Papyrus_Presentation_FR.htm) in an iPhone / iPad application in order to display DICOM medical images?

I have the Papyrus toolkit integrated with my Objective-C code, but I am struggling to get it to display a DICOM image.  Does anyone have any tips they can share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Papyrus is severely outdated, as it was last updated in 1996.  [Here's a link for the manual.](http://www.dim.hcuge.ch/papyrus/PapyUsrMan35.pdf)

Instead, I recommend porting the [DCMFramework currently bundled with OsiriX](http://osirix.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/osirix/Documentation/Guides/index.html) to the iOS instead.  This takes many of the advantages of CoreData, Objective-C, and Mac OS X portability.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Since your post I have been trawling through the Osirix code and trying to separate just the viewer component - what fun lol... Papyrus now in trash can !

Comment: @rick, yeah, it's a bit of a mess.