# How can I use the ITK library to load DICOM images on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, dicom, itk

I'm trying to show a DICOM image on the iPhone / iPad, and was looking at the [ITK library](http://www.itk.org/itkindex.html) as a way of doing this.  Does anyone know how to build this library for iOS, or have any sample code for this?

I have been [trying all the different libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668964/has-anyone-used-the-papyrus-toolkit-in-an-iphone-ipad-application-to-view-dicom) to show a DICOM file, but I need some help with an example so I can learn from it.

Comment: Do you really mean "show it in Xcode" or do you mean "display it in my Cocoa application on an iOS device"? Removing the Xcode tag for now ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GDCM with ITK to read DICOM, like : http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/DICOM/ResampleDICOM

To build ITK on IOS, you can read : http://www.insight-journal.org/download/viewpdf/755/1

But you can use DCMFramework (used in OsiriX) or DCMTK presented in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jvw1TUS4IK0 (to build DCMTK, you can read http://blog.skuld-project.net/index.php?post/2011/03/01/Skuld-on-IOS-part4-dcmtk or search on http://forum.dcmtk.org)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a paper on building itk for ios.

http://www.sfu.ca/~zfh/IJ_755_1_BuildingITKinTheiPhone.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The internal library used by ITK is GDCM. Simply grab it from sf.net:

http://sf.net/projects/gdcm

Answer (score 0):

Instructions for building ITK on IOS are in the PDF at this site: [Insight Journal Article](http://www.insight-journal.org/browse/publication/755)

Comment: Thanks for the link Sean - I found this last week and complied all the libraries in xcode 3 and xcode 4. It was all looking good until I found xcode 4 did not recognise any of them once I tried to link it to my project - another problem to add to my rowing list :-)